# Matlab to C++ conversion

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm trying to write a program in C++ based on matlab code, but i dont understand some of the syntax and i'm not used to dynamic programming -

```
[~, min_index] = min(new_energy(min_l,L_a(min_l):L_b(min_l)));
min_index = L_a(min_l) + min_index - 1; % correct index in the entire image
```

where 'new_energy' is a matrix.

my questions are :

1.how do you find the min of one term(in the first line)? it seems as if i don't understand this : notation.

2.also what does [~,min_index] mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MATLAB, the colon notation `:` means we are referring to a range of values or simply an array of values.

Colon operator is used to generate a sequence of values e.g. `1:5` will return an array `[1 2 3 4 5]`. Read more about colon operator [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html).

So `L_a(min_l):L_b(min_l)` is a range of values. e.g suppose if the value of `L_a(min_l)` is **10** and value of `L_b(min_l)` is **20**, then the resultant range would be:

`[10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]`.

Now, parentheses operator ([index operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)) on a matrix is used to access a submatrix of a larger matrix. It takes a single integer or a range of integers to specify the range of submatrix we want to access. So in the following line

```
new_energy(min_l, L_a(min_l):L_b(min_l))
```

We are selecting a submatrix from `new_energy` matrix. That submatrix is actually the row number `min_l` of the matrix and all the columns specified by the range as I explained before. So by executing this statement, we are getting a single row of the matrix as output.

Next we are executing the `min` function of MATLAB on the row we just extracted.

A variant of the [min](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) function of MATLAB can return the minimum value as well as the index of that minimum value in a range.

```
[minValue, indexOfMinValue] = min(...);
```

If a MATLAB function returns multiple values, and we specify `~` in place of a return variable, it means we do not need that result and that value is not returned by the function.

`[~,min_index]` means we are getting only the index of minimum value and not the minimum value itself as we have specified that we do not need it.